# Optimize linear equations for maximum minimum value

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, pulp

I have a set of linear equations, I want to optimize in such a way that the minimum outcome of any equation is best possible.

```
for example

Solve for
x1*1 + x2*2 
x1*3 + x2*4

constraint
x1+x2=<12
```

I am doing linear maximization with Pulp in python and results yield one output too large and other too small. Currently, I am checking the best minimum possible value by setting another constraint

```
x1*1 + x2*2 >= minval
x1*3 + x2*4 >= minval
```

I am now iterating for the best possible value of minval till the problem is unfeasible, but this is CPU costly way to do as optimization runs for each value of **minval**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new variable `z` and new constraints `z <= x1 + 2*x2` and `z <= 3*x1 + 4*x2`, then maximize `z`. This is similar to what you tried with `minval`, but telling the linear programming solver to optimize the value instead of fiddling it up and down yourself.